# Adding ambient data to the thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I want to add custom data to the thread. For example, ambient transaction scope are stored in the thread as well as identity info. I would like to have my own ambient data available. Is there a way to do this OTB or would there be a lot of work that just isnt worth it?

Let's say that I have a using

```
using(var x = new MyDataClass())
{
 SomeMethod();
}
```

In `SomeMethod()` I want to have access to the instance of MyDataClass that was declared in the calling method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for [`ThreadStaticAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx), unless I completely misunderstood the question.

This article - [Thread Local Storage: Thread-Relative Static Fields and Data Slots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sby1byh.aspx), may be of interest.

Comment: This seems like what I need, but i'll have to mess with it to be sure.